# How to get folder structure and file contents from Sublime

Tags: python, api, sublimetext2

I want to display the tree structure of my folder as well as file contents on a webpage by using a shortcut in sublime.

I'm thinking the right approach is to get the folder data in whatever datastructure it is given to me as...construct a POST request to an endpoint and then deconstruct the POST body for display purposes.

1) Is this directionally right or is there a simpler way?

2) What are the sublime API calls that would help with this?

3) Is there some open source code i can browse through that does anything similar?

4) Could the contents of the post be too huge?

Any general advice would be helpful!